# setting menu item property from another form in oracle

Tags: forms, oracle

good day, i am working on a system using Oracle Forms Builder. i have 3 forms, MAIN, LOGIN, and REGISTER and a menu form named MENU_MAIN, it is attached to the 3 forms, the first form that will be shown is the MAIN, i made some buttons disabled because the user cant access unless they are registered and login, now my problem is, after they login they are prompted again to the MAIN and i need the button that is disabled to be enabled, how can i do that? am i gonna put the code on the LOGIN? thanks for the response

Comment: Why have you written your own LOGIN screen instead of using the built-in Forms functionality?  If you re-invent the wheel, you must expect to re-invent the axle and the crankshaft too.

Answer (score 0):

> "am i gonna put the code on the LOGIN?"

Well I honestly don't know which other part of your application can know that a user has logged in, so yes, the LOGIN screen has to handle this.

What should it do?  It should set a value in a global variable.  Your MAIN screen should interrogate the global variable, probably in a `When-New-Form-Instance` trigger, and set the buttons' properties accordingly.